# Unable to add slideshow without hiding header

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, css-transitions

I am trying to implement slideshow by displaying header at the top without fading.
I am unable to do that.Can somebody help me in changing the code so that the slideshow starts under the header

Here is the link to my codepen

https://codepen.io/arunkayathi/pen/EbxpEv

```
#landing-header {
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size:100%;
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  width:340px;
  height:174px;
  text-align: center;
  margin:0 auto;
  padding-top: 37vh;
}
#landing-content{
  padding:40px 0;
}
#landing-header{
  color:white;
}
.slideshow {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.slideshow li {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 0;
  animation: imageAnimation 50s linear infinite;
}
```

Please click the link and find the entire code for it

Comment: If i am not mistaken, you want the banner/navigation at the very top to remain visible at all times but it is currently fading in and out with the slide change?

Comment: Yes that's correct  chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add a z-index on the nav element.

Add this to your css

```
nav  {
  z-index:10;
}
```